# Passing URLs as Parameters to CGI Script

Tags: bash, shell, url, cgi

I'm working in the bash shell and I'm trying to loop through every parameter being passed to my cgi script via an html page, via a URL. I'm unsure if using for i in "$@" is doing what i need. I need to loop through every parameter passed by the URL.

```
for site in "$@"
do
p=`links -dump $site`
done
```

An example URL would be the following:

```
cgi/word?http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wienermobile+http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple
```

Where the two URLs are my parameters.

I'm pretty new to in depth cgi use and use between webpages and script so excuse me if this is a simple fix.

Answer (score 1):

The example you give isn't actually a valid URL, because it's not correctly escaped (see "Percent-encoding" at wikipedia, for example)

```
cgi/word?http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wienermobile+http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple
```

should probably be more like

```
cgi/word?http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FWienermobile%20http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FApple
```

HTTP is not a trivial protocol and you might be best off using a framework, and not to write in shell (this has increased security risk for all the pitfalls shell comes with)

But just for the fun of it, here's a sample CGI script in shell which decodes the query string.

```
#!/bin/sh

percentdecode() {
    /usr/bin/printf "$(/usr/bin/printf %s "$1" | sed -e 's/%/\\x/g; s/+/ /g')"
}

qsdecode() (
    IFS=\&
    for kv in $QUERY_STRING ; do
        IFS==
        set -- $kv
        if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
            echo "Not a valid key-value pair: $kv"
            continue
        fi
        k=$(percentdecode "$1")
        v=$(percentdecode="$2")

        echo "Key: $k"
        echo "Value: $v" 
    done
}


cat <<'EOF'
Status: 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8

EOF

qsdecode
```

This parses the conventional query string format which transmits a key-value store as
`?a=b&c=d&e=f`. You are best advised to follow this format format as well. If you must stay with something like `?value1+value2+value3` then that's very simple to parse:

```
decode_plusdelimited() (
    unset IFS
    # percentdecode maps '+' and '%20' to ' '
    for value in $(percentdecode "$QUERY_STRING"); do
        echo "Got value: $value"
    done
)
```

(note that you didn't give a precise specification for plus-delimited format, so this is just an approximation)